# Does the filter hold?

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

In a table, I placed a filter on the amount column to be 50,000 and less.  When I run SUMX() on that table, do I need to be concerned that the filtered amount goes away?

My sumx looks like this:

```
<£50k =
SUMX (
    FILTER ( 'LTM 050K',
        'LTM 050K'[pc_regionno] = 'LTM Live'[pc_regionno]
         && 'LTM 050K'[statuscode] = 866120000
         || 'LTM 050K'[statuscode] = 866120007
         && 'LTM 050K'[createdon] >= 'LTM Live'[xxxBegin]
         && 'LTM 050K'[createdon]  <= 'LTM Live'[xxxEnd]
    ),
    'LTM 050K'[tsg_quoteprice_base]
)
```

In the SUMX(), I am not putting an amount filter because I am counting on the amount filter to hold.  Is this correct?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, existing filtering should hold unless you remove it via an `ALL` type of function.

If you have a report/page/visual level filter on `'LTM 050K'[amount]`, then that filtered table is what gets passed into the `FILTER` function. In other words, the first argument of the `FILTER` function does necessarily take the whole table you specify, but rather that table *after* it has been modified by its filter context.

Comment: Would you please give me an example of how to limit a dollar amount in the above SUMX()?  Less than 50000 and a between 50001 and 100000?  Thank you for your response, @Alexis Olson.

Comment: It depends on how you want to limit it. If you just want to filter any rows in the table where `'LTM 050K'[amount]` is in that range, then just add that condition in your filter (`&& LTM 050K'[amount] < 50000`). If you're talking about an aggregated amount, then you need to do a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether or not the amounts filtered on the actual report page will persist to your report measures the answer is yes.